# Inserting rows in to a table using WHERE condition and JOIN from another table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables (say table 1 and table 2) and I have 8 columns in each table(v_id, p_id, cat, s1, s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,u_name,P_date)

I want to insert values into table1 from table2 with following conditions:

1. if v_id already exists in table1, and p_id in table 2 matches with table 1, it should replace the v_id in table 1 with v_id in table 2
2. if v_id doesn't exist in table 1, it should just add those v_ids to table 1
3. if v_id exists, but p_id in table 2 doesn't match with table 1, it should add v_ids to table 1

so far, I tried:

I have initiated the tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(v_id, cat TEXT, s1 TEXT,s2 TEXT,s3 TEXT, s4 TEXT,s5 TEXT,s6 TEXT, u_name TEXT, p_date DATE, p_id TEXT)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2(v_id, cat TEXT, s1 TEXT,s2 TEXT,s3 TEXT, s4 TEXT,s5 TEXT,s6 TEXT, u_name TEXT, p_date DATE, p_id TEXT)
```

I have inserted some data in to table 1 and table 2 and tried the following code:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.v_id=table1.v_id
WHERE table2.p_id=table1.p_id OR table1.v_id IS NULL
```

But, it gives me the following error:

```
"table table1 has 11 columns but 22 values were supplied"
```

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: This is why you don't use `SELECT *` outside of interactive testing. You have all the columns from the two tables you join together.

Comment: @shawn Hi,  could you suggest me the approach in code??  I am very novice to SQL..

Answer (score 0):

This `SELECT *` is returning 22 columns. Why? Because it is returning the columns from the `JOIN`, not only those from `table2`. From the [sqlite SELECT doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

> If the join-operator is a "LEFT JOIN" or "LEFT OUTER JOIN", then after
>   the ON or USING filtering clauses have been applied, an extra row is
>   added to the output for each row in the original left-hand input
>   dataset that corresponds to no rows at all in the composite dataset
>   (if any). The added rows contain NULL values in the columns that would
>   normally contain values copied from the right-hand input dataset.

`SELECT table2.* from .....` would fix *that* problem.

Let's forget about the INSERT for a moment and evaluate what rows will be returned by

```
SELECT * FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.v_id=table1.v_id
WHERE table2.p_id=table1.p_id OR table1.v_id IS NULL
```

It will not select rows where `table2.v_id = table1.v_id AND table2.p_id != table1.p_id` so condition 3 will never be met.

Unless table1 has a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint, there will never be a replace, so condition 1 will never be met (it will simply insert the rows from table2). From the sqlite ON CONFLICT doc:

> **REPLACE**
>
> When a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the
>   constraint violation prior to inserting or updating the current row
>   and the command continues executing normally. If a NOT NULL constraint
>   violation occurs, the REPLACE conflict resolution replaces the NULL
>   value with the default value for that column, or if the column has no
>   default value, then the ABORT algorithm is used. If a CHECK constraint
>   violation occurs, the REPLACE conflict resolution algorithm always
>   works like ABORT.

You will need to create index(es) on table1 in order to use the `REPLACE` action. Perhaps a composite index on v_id, p_id would do the trick. Something like `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "vid_pid_idx" on table1 (v_id,p_id)`. Then simply `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2` to accomplish the objectives.

Rows where v_ids and p_ids are equal will "REPLACE" because the UNIQUE constraint will be "violated".
All other rows from table2 will be inserted.